# Was my question closed because it should be a community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, close-reasons

I asked a question on Stack Overflow, but it was closed because it is "subjective". Someone mentioned that not making it a community wiki could be the problem.

Should a subjective question be a community wiki?

Comment: No, don't repost it.

Comment: An interesting discussion would be whether it is ok to create one meta question for each closed question in SO. But I'll leave that for Meta Meta StackOverflow.

Comment: It has been reopened now.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, it's a little bit like "Mama! Stevie closed my question!" -- "Stevie, give your little brother his question back!" -- "But Mama..." -- "No 'But Mama'! Go ahead and reopen it now!" -- "Yes Mama... *stupid little brother* " -- "What was that?" -- "Nothing, Mom. I'll be searching for dupes now."

Comment: @balpha it is definitely a case of sour grapes, but we all do that when we're downvoted over something we consider reasonable. Though you have to love the irony of not knowing the answer to a question relating to knowledge transfer.

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot delete this question. But I did not understand the reasons for closing my SO question. There was no comment about the closing reason. Also it was marked as "subjective and argumentative" what confused me. Besides that Meta SO has a special "support" tag, which looked like I am allowed to ask for closing reasons.

Comment: @Christian: It's absolutely okay that you asked this. We're just having a little fun here. Cheers!

Comment: @Christian, CW is not 'intended' for subjective or 'one-answer-only' questions, but it's often used for that as a defense against those who close questions that they don't think they can get good information out of, or doesn't apply to their niche. Your question shouldn't have to be CW since it's asking for specific answers, but it should be closed because it's a duplicate of multiple other questions.

Comment: And now it's closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My opinion: The question is fine. Yes, it's a candidate for "community wiki," because there's no real one-and-only answer, but now that you made it wiki, it's okay. I voted to reopen.

Closing this question as "subjective and argumentative" was wrong. The definition of this close reason is

> It's impossible to objectively answer this question, and the question was asked in a confrontational, argumentative way.

The first part holds for your question, the second one definitely doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

> Afterwards I realized that not making
>   it a community wiki could be the
>   problem. Was that the problem?

I don't know. I think it's an interesting question. It is true that it is a typical community wiki question, but don't worry about that - it *is* already marked as community wiki.

> Should I repost it? Because I think it
>   is unlikely that a closed question
>   will be reopened.

No, don't repost it. It has been reopened already. In any case, **never post duplicates of your own closed questions**.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really relevant anymore, in the passing years the rules became much more strict and subjective questions are no longer accepted, regardless if Community Wiki or not.

Community Wiki pretty much lost it glamour and used very rarely on Stack Overflow, for canonical answers that need collaborative editing by many users, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186#4660186).

Answer (score -1):

Community wiki, yes.  There's no finite answer to the question.  But closure seems harsh - there are a lot of open questions regarding estimating tasks.  Your question about knowledge transfer between developers seems just as appropriate.

Comment: +1: agreed.  And not sure why this was downvoted...

Answer (score -1):

The actual title is "How to make developers learn from each other?". That sounds confrontational, at best, and may be why some people thought the question was argumentative.

I think it's a good question. I'm glad it's back open.

Comment: So, why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: It is Meta, so it means people disagreed with your opinion i.e. thought the question is not good and shouldn't have been reopened.